# Using gpu-loadsensor with Grid Engine

Tags: sungridengine, qsub

How do I use the [gpu-loadsensor](https://arc.liv.ac.uk/repos/darcs/sge/source/dist/util/resources/loadsensors/gpu-loadsensor.c) with Grid Engine? I would like to set up NVIDIA GPUs as a resource on my cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Compile it.  Run it with --help it will give you a list of complex variables to add to your complex configuration.  Add it to the list of load_sensors in the sge_conf.  Users can now request the defined resources in order to route their jobs to the right nodes.

It's a load sensor not complete integration though.

Answer (score 0):

There are other Grid Engine GPU integrations but they are for commercial products, such as Univa Grid Engine.  You can find Univa Grid Engine here at http://www.univa.com.  Univa has a free trial download that you can get from their website.  You could always download and try it to see if it is worth it or not.